# set programmatically focus when new content is loaded on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-router, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to set up automatically focus on first loaded article. (f.e. user clicks on the button "load more" and new articles are loaded).

**My react implementation:**

I'm using `ref` attribute in `<Link>` component, which is from react-router library and then I'm calling `focus()` method in lifecycle method `componentDidMount()`.

**It works on all devices except iOS.** If I turn on voiceover on iphone and then on webpage I click on the button, it doesn't automatically focus on first loaded article). It works just with html anchor tag.

I read some articles before and it looks that it's not possible to do this in this way but only with firing some event f.e. **click event**.

Can someone confirm that it's not possible to solve it in this way or there is any workaround without using jquery ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Hi, No... In my opinion there is no solution and I think it's "bug" in iOS.

Comment: Looks like that, I opened a new question about this and no answers or any feedback at all

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering about this, I found this article:

https://medium.com/swlh/how-ios-voiceover-demonstrates-the-power-and-flexibility-of-react-5369679b6a6b

I'm in the process of moving from CRA to a new react framework. So far I've tried Next.js, gatsby, remix, expo. The issue that I'm running into is that I've gone through an WCAG test run, and basically the standards require you to focus the first header on events like when you open a modal or switch to a new page. I've used react-router-dom as it allows for manual control over focus behavior between page transitions (though it does get a bit annoying to manually focus things) - however with the expiration of CRA, I have to come up with a good solution that is compliant. Server-rendered solutions do this by triggering a page load, which causes Safari (not Chrome! it's broken at the moment) in iOS to focus the first item on the page. In OSX, the page load causes Voiceover to read out the entire contents of the page. In Next.js and Gatsby using client-side routing, the focus must be manually handled after page transition (as otherwise it just focuses in the middle of the page where you clicked).

For a while I that my useEffect(()=> ref.current.focus()) wasn't working because of a problem with the framework. But now that I found that bit in the article (I ran into the same issue in Remix, it worked root.tsx but didn't work in a route - which means I was missing something), I think I have to re-explore Next.js / Expo / Gatsby again as perhaps the bad focus behavior was being caused by VO not focusing on an interactive element (I've done this previously, but I always handled focus by changing focus to a button, so I didn't realize there was an 'interactive element' limitation to Voiceover's ability to element.focus()). Apparently voiceover won't focus on an `<h1>` or a `<div>`, but will focus on an `<a>`, `<button>`, `<input>`, or `<h1 tabindex="0">` (the 0 is important apparently) or `<div tabindex="0">`.

(According to chatgpt, the "interactive elements" are: a href, button, input, select, textarea, label, details, iframe, audio, video, [tabindex], map+area)

Voiceover iOS (and OSX) behavior for handling focus when client-side routing is to basically focus whatever element is nearest to what you clicked on the next page. This is a bit of a buggy behavior. In remix, clicking on an  will reset the focus to the top of the page (and then read out the page on OSX), but this loses redux/client state. So for my project, the only option is to handle focus manually with client-side routing, which apparently requires me to put a tabindex on all my headers before trying to get iOS to focus on it.